# Python equivalent for R's 'zoo' package

Tags: python, r, pandas, time-series, zoo

Are there Python or perhaps `pandas` equivalents to R's `zoo` package?

In particular, I'm looking for equivalents to:

```
dataLag2 = lag(zoo(train$data), -2, na.pad=TRUE)
train$dataLag2 = coredata(dataLag2)
```

Are there equivalents on Python that would produce the same results (the [empty entry for `zoo` functionality in the Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html?highlight=zoo#zoo) is a bit ominous).

Comment: is `lag(zoo(...` different from [`.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift)?

Comment: This might be a good place to start http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=268 & http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @behzad.nouri: Wow, I'm always amazed at how complicate R makes simple things seem.

Comment: It's not a direct answer but there is a binding of R in python: Rpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has the TimeSeries class which implements all the functionalities available in zoo to manipulate and homogenize irregular time series data:

if 'ts' is a TimeSeries object containing irregular hourly timestamped data I'd first create an homogeneous time series doing:

```
ts.resample('H').interpolate()
```

And after, to create a lagged timeseries I'd use the shift() method. For example, to lag the previous timeseries 12 hours backwards:

```
ts.shift(-12)
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html

Comment: do you want to contribute this for the zoo section in comparison with r - pls open a pull request !